# Submodule dependencies with Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a project structure like:

[image]

However, whenever I run `mvn clean test -DskipTests` from the `Project 1` directory, it ends up NOT including the `Project 2` module in the Maven reactor even though I've listed it as a dependency in `Project 1` as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.main.sub</groupId>
  <artifactId>project2-artId</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

What could be happening and why isnt the dependency being recognized?

Comment: what do you mean by "not recognized"- do you mean the module is not existent, or that you expect it to be recompiled and it isn't, or else?

Comment: @Daniele I expect it to be recompiled but it isnt. I am maybe messing up the multi module idea

Comment: well are they both modules of the same parent project? You can build the parent instead

Answer (score 1):

From https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html; the reactor "Collects all the available modules to build". (modules of the project that is currently being built)

You need to: create a parent project, with packaging `pom`; add two modules to this project (one for Project1, one for Project2), and submodules for project1.

Then, when you build the parent project, the build order for all modules are decided by the reactor-